# How to add custom template in Admin Order

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, template

I am currently creating a button for a single order in Magento(next to invoice, ship, reorder etc.). I would like the button to be inside a template to allow for php variables from that order and external js files to be added.

I am currently trying to override the sales order view page and add code from their, this seems to be the best/simplest way. It's reading the new template, but everything else is getting messed up. How do i fix this?

app\code\local\MyApp\OrderButton\etc\config.xml

```
<config>
<modules>
    <MyApp_OrderButton>
        <version>0.0.1</version>
    </MyApp_OrderButton>
</modules>
<global>
    <models>
        <myapp_orderbutton>
            <class>MyApp_OrderButton_Model</class>
        </myapp_orderbutton>
    </models>
    <blocks>
        <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view_info>ShipRush_OrderButton_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
    </blocks>
</global>
</config>
```

app\code\local\MyApp\OrderButton\Block\Sales\Order\View\info.php:

```
class MyApp_OrderButton_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info
{
    protected function _construct()
    {
       $this->setTemplate('myapp/sales/order/view/myinfo.phtml');
    }
}
```

Potential template, php, and js:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function connect() {
    var allsongs = '<?php echo $x ?>';
    lib = {
        songs: allsongs,
        albums: 20
    };
    alert(lib);
}
</script>
```

This is read by magento, but it messes up the whole page:
[image]

Comment: Could you add the JS function and explain what you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @R.S The javascript function has added scripts from www.example.com/api/myapp/myjs.js and a popup window from example.com comes up. I would like the clicking of the button to trigger this function, but have the button, php, and js all connected, so it must be in a template.

Comment: @R.S code added

Comment: What type is `$x`? Unless it is a int or object then it should be `var allsongs = '<?php echo $x ?>'` (you are missing the `echo`) Also what error are you getting?

Comment: @R.S question updated

Comment: Take a look at your php/magento error log. Also instead of rewriting the block try using an admin theme or setTemplate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe your first question is you are not able to override `info.phtml` file.
If that's the case then

Change your **layout** this way:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout>
    <adminhtml_sales_order_view>
        <reference name="order_tab_info">
            <action method="setTemplate">
                <template>myapp/sales/order/view/info.phtml</template>
            </action>
        </reference>
    </adminhtml_sales_order_view>
</layout>
```

**IMP**

Remember if you using layout file to override template then you don't need to rewrite block in `config.xml`, unless you are also overriding some function or adding new function to it.

```
       <adminhtml>
            <rewrite>
                <sales_order_view_info>MyApp_OrderButton_Block_Sales_Order_View_Info</sales_order_view_info>
            </rewrite>
        </adminhtml>
```

**Magento layout `setTemplate` is so powerful that it will handle the work for you.**

Answer (score 0):

Instead of rewriting the Info block just to make changes to the template file, you may want to consider creating an admin theme. See [Magento - Override adminhtml template file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14719777/want-to-over-ride-adminhtml-in-magento)

Assuming that your rewrite is working correctly (by view page source or use magento template hint)

Change

```
var allsongs = <?php $x ?>;
```

to

```
var allsongs = <?php echo $x ?>;
//or
var allsongs = '<?php echo $x ?>';
```